# After clicking a hamburger icon, the menu does not display above slide-show images on the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do not know how to show the menu above the slide-show images after clicking the hamburger icon. I used z-index and .addClass in order to add the diplay:none property to the #slideshow. This did not work. I do not know what I can do next.

https://jsfiddle.net/ft31scgw/
[image]

main.js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#slideshow .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        dots: true,
    });
});

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#userReview .slick').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 8000,
        dots: true,
    });
});
    function hMenu() {
        var menu = document.getElementById("toggle");
        if(menu) {
            var hide = $("#slideshow").hide();
            } else {
            var show = $("#slideshow").show();
            }
    }
</script>
```

style.css
enter image description here

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #slideshow {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#slideshow {
    div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
    img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
}
    button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .logo img {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 473px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    label{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    .menu {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
        background: black;
    }
    .menu a {
         display: block;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
         margin: 1;
    }
    #toggle:checked + .menu {
        display: block;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #slideshow {
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .disappear {
        display:none;
        z-index: -2;
    }
```

}/* @media min-width 736px */

index.html

```
   <div id="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <h1><img src="img/logo.png" widht="473px" height="50px"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="hMenu()" />
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="http://joeynamiki.com/" target="_blank">Work</a>
            <a href="about.php">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <a href="https://medium.com/@wcgwd1" target="_blank">Blog</a>
            <a href="contact.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /#header -->

    <section id="slideshow">
        <div class="slick">
            <div><img src="img/image1.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img src="img/image2.jpg" alt=""></div>
            <div><img src="img/image3.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: try giving z-index

Answer (score 1):

Good to know, that z-index specifies the stack order of **siblings** elements. In your case `<div class="header">` needs z-index greater than `<section id="slideshow">`. z-index only works on positioned elements, so both of them should have `position:relative`. I made a working example for you on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0h4sz9to/).

Comment: Hi @Levente Gabos I see. I will check everything you said out. I did not care the header. I will also check that. Thank you!